# why does coffeescript end my function before it is supposed to end

Tags: coffeescript

I am doing a project using coffeescript. In on instance it seems to end a function in despite there being no reason. I am using d3 as well so all that function chaining might be the reason the compiler fails. Or am I missing something

This:

```
render3Circles = (pageName) ->
    dataset = [
        Math.random()
        Math.random()
        Math.random()]
    svg = d3.select("#"+pageName)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", "400")
        .attr("height", "400")
    # add arcs + tip circles
    arcs = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
    tipCircles = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
    tipCircles.attr("fill", (d,i) ->
            colors[i]
        )
        .attr("cx", (d, i) ->
            100
        )
        .attr("cy", (d, i) ->
            150
        )
        .attr("r", arcWidth/2)
    arcs.attr("d", drawArc)
        .attr("fill", (d,i) ->
            colors[i]
        )
        .attr("class", "arc-path")                  # assigns a class for easier selecting
        .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)")    # sets position--easier than setting x's and y's
        .attr("d", drawArc)
    svg.attr "style", "opacity:0.5;margin-top:20px;"
```

compiles to this:

```
render3Circles = function(pageName) {
  var arcs, dataset, svg, tipCircles;
  dataset = [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random()];
  svg = d3.select("#" + pageName).append("svg").attr("width", "400").attr("height", "400");
  arcs = svg.selectAll("path").data(dataset).enter().append("path");
  tipCircles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataset).enter().append("circle");
  return tipCircles.attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  }).attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return 100;
  }).attr("cy", function(d, i) {
    return 150;
  }).attr("r", arcWidth / 2);
};

arcs.attr("d", drawArc).attr("fill", function(d, i) {
  return colors[i];
}).attr("class", "arc-path").attr("transform", "translate(200,200)").attr("d", drawArc);

svg.attr("style", "opacity:0.5;margin-top:20px;");
```

The function just ends before I start drawing the arcs. It does the same thing if I switch the arcs and the circles part.

CoffeeScript version: 1.6.1
Ubuntu server 12.04

Comment: You have some indentation problem that cannot be reproduced with the code you've given us, which compiles fine: http://bit.ly/1lWZHCc.  Consider replacing tabs with two spaces for indentation.

Comment: I tried exactly that. It compiles fine for me online as well. Just not on my ubuntu server. Coffeescript version: 1.2.0. command: coffee -cb . (edit: I just realized, that my coffescript version is out of date. brb upgrading...)

Comment: Err, well, 1.2.0 is almost 3 years old. Consider upgrading.

Comment: I just upgraded to 1.6.1 and still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I corrected this bug by updateing node and npm, then installing the newest version of coffee script (1.7.1 at the time)

I hope I can save someone a few hours with this answer. (installing node from github takes some time. I did it over night)